# Copy and paste form into project is not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I accidentally deleted my form file, so I restored through Recycle Bin. However, I found that it's not in my project so I selected [Projectname].vb, [Projectname].designer.vb, and [Projectname].resx in 'Add Existing Item' dialog in Solution Explorer. It was successfully added, but I found that there's thousands of errors that show me things are already declared. And all thing in designer.vb not applied to designer. So I tried delete form files and add again, add .vb file only, etc. But not working at all, and it came even worth, so designer even not open now! [Error while showing Designer Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCaYy.png)
[Error in designer.vb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I90m5.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to copy files from windows explorer. you should copy the three vb file.

In Visual Studio, just add the base `.vb` file
Just press **Ctrl+D** or right click your **project -> Add -> Existing Item**